# GDB file and USA Base Map.mxd not in the same directory ArcObjects

Tags: arcobjects

I am trying to open a address locator in ArcObjects by following this tutorial: http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Creating_an_address_locator/0001000004pm000000/

The code sample has this line: 
String workspacePath = @"C:\UnitedStates.gdb";

I talked to an analyst and they told me to find the sample in this folder 
"C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\DeveloperKit10.0\Samples\data\Usa"

And that has a file called USA.gdb

However my "USA Base Map.mxd" file is located here, Z:\ESRI\DataMaps10\usa

It seems like ArcEngine should use the same map / data to do both geocoding and projections... right?  Am I doing something obviously wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The geoprocessing tool takes a path to a GDB file as input but it should also be able to take a FeatureClass as input:

> Misstatement—Geoprocessing tools only
>   take datasets on disk as input and
>   only write datasets to disks. Another
>   way this has been stated is that
>   geoprocessing is "pathname to
>   pathname" only. Only pathnames to
>   datasets can be used as input and
>   output parameters.  In fact, you can
>   use equivalent ArcObjects anywhere
>   features classes are expected. For
>   example, you can do the following:
>   Pass an object with IFeatureClass or
>   IDataset as input to a tool instead of
>   a pathname string. Create in-memory
>   feature classes, manipulate them, and
>   use them in geoprocessing tools. Use
>   the special in-memory FeatureSet and
>   RecordSet objects instead of feature
>   classes and tables. These two objects
>   behave like their on-disk
>   counterparts.

[Geoprocessing misstatements](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/Using_geoprocessing_to_develop_applications/0001000001wt000000/) So I guess you should be able to get a FeatureClass from your map and pass it as an in-parameter to the geoprocessingtool.

Comment: Any idea how to get a featureclass from my map?

Comment: On the IMap object you have a ILayer layers collection, search for you layer in that collection. When you find your layer cast it to a IFeatureLayer it has a FeatureClass property.

Answer (score 1):

apparently this is normal.   The geodatabase is not in the same dir as the ISO maps.  I think my GDB is still corrupt tho

Comment: Correct! The MXD has a datasource that could be a GDB or shapefile somewere else on your machine or mayby even a server layer. If you open the MXD in ArcMap you should be able to see what datasource is's connected to. I haven't seen any resources on what datasources that are valid.